# Algorithm for purely categorical data

Tags: clustering, categorical-data

Looking for an algorithm to deal with purely categorical data.  It was suggested to me to look into the K-medoids algorithm.  Anyone know if there is a K-medoids algorithm R library(package)?

Answer (score 1):

K-medoids of course works for purely categorical data.

But there also is k-modes, easy to find with a little bit of research... It's much cheaper to run, it is O(n), not O(n²)

It doesn't solve the problem that categorical data usually will not cluster in a *meaningful* way...

Comment: Categorical data *without a (partial) order* usually does not cluster in a meaningful way. In fact introducing partial order, i.e. a structure, is adding messing meaning to categories that otherwise would be just labels.